# How to shuffle a particular cell in html table?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How to shuffle a particular td every refresh the page? I have this Multiple Choice examination and I like to give a twist that every refresh the choices will shuffle, but the choices I have is inside table. I want to shuffle only the A,B, and C column.

Here's my code

```js
var el
function togCell(col, asn) {
    if (typeof event !== 'undefined')
        el = event.srcElement
    for (var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.cells.length; i++)
        el.parentNode.cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
    el.style.backgroundColor = col;
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TESTING FIRST QUESTION</td>
    <td onclick="togCell('#90ee90','AnsSelected_1')">FIRST Choices Correct</td>
    <td onclick="togCell('#90ee90','AnsSelected_1')">FIRST Choices Wrong</td>
    <td onclick="togCell('#90ee90','AnsSelected_1')">FIRST FIRST Choices Wrong</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TESTING SECOND QUESTION</td>
    <td onclick="togCell('#90ee90','AnsSelected_1')">SECOND Choices Wrong</td>
    <td onclick="togCell('#90ee90','AnsSelected_1')">SECOND Choices Wrong</td>
    <td onclick="togCell('#90ee90','AnsSelected_1')">SECOND Choices Correct</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Expected output

| Question | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TESTING FIRST QUESTION | FIRST Choices Wrong | FIRST Choices Wrong | FIRST Choices Correct |
| TESTING SECOND QUESTION | SECOND Choices Wrong | SECOND Choices Correct | SECOND Choices Wrong |

Comment: put the answers inside an array and shuffle that, then put the answers in the cells

Comment: @ale it is dynamically generated with the answerID attribute, I don't think it will work. is there any other logic aside from that>?

Comment: in fact your question it is curious :) you should start from a list of question, with the id of the correct aswer, for every question a list of answers and every answer should have an 'answerid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that why don't I put the whole td in variable then pass it into an array? since I can't put only the text content because I also have the id's that I need. This is what I've come up with

```js
let tdA = `<td ansID="1" choicesID="1">FIRST Choices Correct</td>`;
let tdB = `<td ansID="1" choicesID="2">FIRST Choices Wrong</td>`;
let tdC = `<td ansID="1" choicesID="3">FIRST FIRST Choices Wrong</td>`;

var choicesArray = [tdA, tdB, tdC];
var shuffle = function (arr) {
  for (var j, x, i = arr.length; i;j = parseInt(Math.random() * i),x = arr[--i],arr[i] = arr[j],arr[j] = x);
  return arr;
}
shuffle(choicesArray);

$('#appendTr').append(
  `<tr>` +
  `<td>TESTING FIRST QUESTION</td>` +
  `${choicesArray[0]}` +
  `${choicesArray[1]}` +
  `${choicesArray[2]}` +
  `</tr>`
);
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="appendTr"></tbody>
</table>
```